# URL Image Sharing Not Working - Ionic Cordova Social Sharing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to share image using SocialSharing Plugin of cordova. It works fine with other urls but with following url it does not work at all. It fails

```
https://api.backendless.com/df1223ca-9cf4-534c-ff07-fb17e4d58700/v1/files/mega/yellowflat%20(1).jpg
```

URL opens correct in browser, i don't know what is wrong with it while sharing via SocialSharing Plugin.

Comment: same prob here bro. you got any answer??